# Tile focus display issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working with a Windows Forms Application (.net/c#)
Using [MetroFramework](https://thielj.github.io/MetroFramework/). Home page contains some MetroTiles. I need to focus on first tile when I launch Home page.

I Can do this focus is working fine. but it could show any indication for selected/focused tile at all. I could not find any properties.

[image]

In above image back Tile is selected now. but could not identify this as user and when I press 'enter' BACK button functionality is working fine. Same for other tiles also. Please help.

Comment: If this matters to you then you are doing it wrong.  This kind of UI design was created for mobile devices without a keyboard.  Phones and slates, they use a touch screen, the tile is the right size for a finger.  Focus only matters if you use a keyboard.  It is just inappropriate design for a desktop machine, otherwise perhaps explains why Windows 8 was so greatly disliked.  So no point in looking for focus support, it isn't there because it didn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no property, but you can use the 'selected' event to change something yourself, like a slightly changed color or drawing a thin line around it.

As far as I know Metro still hasn't a built in a functionality for this case.
So try to use the workaround if possible.